# How to retrieve a streamed response (e.g. download a file) with Symfony test client

Tags: symfony, streaming, symfony-2.1, functional-testing

I am writing functional tests with Symfony2.

I have a controller that calls a `getImage()` function which streams an image file as follows:

```php
public function getImage($filePath)
    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/png');

    $response->setCallback(function () use ($filePath) {
        $bytes = @readfile(filePath);
        if ($bytes === false || $bytes <= 0)
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    });

    return $response;
}
```

In functional testing, I try to request the content with the [Symfony test client](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/testing.html#working-with-the-test-client) as follows:

```php
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('GET', $url);
$content = $client->getResponse()->getContent();
```

The problem is that `$content` is empty, I guess because the response is generated as soon as the HTTP headers are received by the client, without waiting for a data stream to be delivered.

Is there a way to catch the content of the streamed response while still using `$client->request()` (or even some other function) to send the request to the server?

Answer (score 23):

The return value of *sendContent* (rather than *getContent*) is the callback that you've set. *getContent* actually just returns *false* in Symfony2

Using *sendContent* you can enable the output buffer and assign the content to that for your tests, like so:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('GET', $url);

// Enable the output buffer
ob_start();
// Send the response to the output buffer
$client->getResponse()->sendContent();
// Get the contents of the output buffer
$content = ob_get_contents();
// Clean the output buffer and end it
ob_end_clean();
```

You can read more on the output buffer [here](http://www.php.net/manual/ref.outcontrol.php)

The API for StreamResponse is [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/StreamedResponse.html)

Comment: For me to get this to work I had to place ob_start() before making the request.

Answer (score 11):

The current best answer used to work well for me for some time, but for some reason it isn't anymore. The response is parsed into a DOM crawler and the binary data is lost.

I could fix that by using the internal response. Here's the git patch of my changes[1]:

```
-        ob_start();
         $this->request('GET', $uri);
-        $responseData = ob_get_clean();
+        $responseData = self::$client->getInternalResponse()->getContent();
```

I hope this can help someone.

[1]: you just need access to the client, which is a 
`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\KernelBrowser`

Comment: Great stuff man, just saved me with this one.

Comment: in symfony 6, $client->getInternalResponse()->getContent() did the job. thanks

Answer (score 10):

For me didn't work like that. Instead, I used ob_start() before making the request, and after the request i used  $content = ob_get_clean() and made asserts on that content.

In test:

```
    // Enable the output buffer
    ob_start();
    $this->client->request(
        'GET',
        '$url',
        array(),
        array(),
        array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json')
    );
    // Get the output buffer and clean it
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    $this->assertEquals('my response content', $content);
```

Maybe this was because my response is a csv file.

In controller:

```
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me also using a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` object.